# Android XML parsing problem

Tags: android, xml

I am having problem in parsing the xml data, below is my code

```
URL url=new URL(Urls.statusUrl);
     SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
     SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
     XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();
     FOIA_Parsing_Handler mxmlparsing=new FOIA_Parsing_Handler();
     xr.setContentHandler(mxmlparsing);
     xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));//Exception at this line

     mStatus=mxmlparsing.getRecords();
     m_adapter=new StatusAdapter(Status_Inquiry.this, R.layout.status_inquiry_view, mStatus);

     mLstViewStatusInquiry.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

I am getting

> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 8299: not well-formed (invalid token)

at above line

Regards
Saurabh

Comment: Show us the XML you're expecting...It's definitely an invalid xml.

Comment: Thanks I think you are correct I am inspecting the xml will revert back later thanks

Comment: Thanks you were correct +1 for pointing in right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by st0le the problem is in xml data I am getting some garbage in xml so the code is coorect

Comment: problem is not with code its with xml so ask web developers to correct it becuase they are sending some junk characters

Comment: Thanks for the response, I downloaded weatherforecast application from anddev.org and its showing the mentioned error, so how can we change that xml. do u have any Idea to get around this problem?

Comment: ask your web developers to fix it